# How to write BdG equation for generalize Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I am reading this parer [**Majorana Corner Modes in a High-Temperature Platform**](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.096803),The Bogoliubov–de
Gennes Hamiltonian is :

$\hat{H}=\sum_{k}\Psi^\dagger_kH(\vec{k})\Psi_k$with

$\Psi_k=(c_{a,k\uparrow},c_{b,k\uparrow},c_{a,k\downarrow},c_{b,k\downarrow},c_{a,-k\uparrow}^\dagger,c_{b,-k\uparrow}^\dagger,c_{a,-k\downarrow}^\dagger,c_{b,-k\downarrow}^\dagger)$
and Hamiltonian is $H(\vec{k})=M(\vec{k})\sigma_z\tau_z+A_xsin(k_x)\sigma_xs_z+A_ysin(k_y)\sigma_y\tau_z+\Delta(\vec{k})s_y\tau_y-\mu\tau_z$.

All of the $\sigma,\tau,s$ are [Pauli Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices),$s$ is in spin space,$\tau$ is about particle-hole symmetry and $\sigma$ represent the orbital.

1. Question1:

I want to solve this model through BdG;I have known use Fourier Transformation make this Hamiltonian in real space.But I cannot confirm the correct process about this,I want to get the BdG form for this Hamiltonian,both k-space and real space are made me happy.

I download the [**Supplemental Material**](https://journals.aps.org/prl/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.096803/supplemental_CMKP.pdf) for this paper which have the Hamiltonian in real space,however I wish I can realize the detail about how to do this.

2. Quextion2:

In article has two image[image: im]
I am a tiro in this,would someone willing to tell me how to plot these image?

Thanks for everyone who answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are no many-body annihilation and creation operators in your matrix hamiltonian, so there is no way to tell if you are dealing with a superconductor or a simple band-theory model. Consequently there is  no BdG version.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,would you mind see that paper,I didn't write a lot about that,you could understand my problem.

Comment: Although you added the annihilation and creations it's still not possible to to work out what you want because you have not specified how the $\sigma$  $\tau$ and $s$  matrices act on the entries in your eight-component field.  I can guess what the $\sigma$ and $\tau$'s do, but the $s_{z,y}$'s are a mystery.

Comment: In the paper,I see that $s_i,\sigma_i,\tau_i$ are Pauli matrices in the spin $(\uparrow,\downarrow)$,orbital (a,b),and particle-hole space,respectively.